# return json collection from entity framework in asp.net mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Asp.net MVC + EF:
When I try to send back to client from controller, 
a collection that I retrieve from EF, I get an error on client.
debug shows that the details are not sent appropriately.
it does work fine when I copy the data into any other DTOs that I created
and send them instead.
just init another object and send it works.
why ???

thanks !!!

Comment: It's usually because you have lazy loading enabled and the serializer tries to read a collection, whish should be lazy loaded, when the context no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

so this is how it should work. reason: poco ef objects can't be serialize properly because of relationships conventions, and we use dto instead to return only required properties.

[WebApi Controller returned value in Entity Framework 5 and MVC 4 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210975/webapi-controller-returned-value-in-entity-framework-5-and-mvc-4-project/13219073#13219073)

hope it helps